# Angular Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, angular-service-worker

I am doing Push notifications in Angular PWA with Firebase and I am following a link to do so. https://medium.com/@tariqueejaz/progressive-web-app-push-notifications-making-the-web-app-more-native-in-nature-a167af22e004

I am using Angular 6 and have setup the code for everything. when I am trying to run it, then it is showing me a pop up [image].

After clicking on Allow button, it is throwing an error on console:

> Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script."
>   code
>   :
>   "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
>   message
>   :
>   "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
>   stack
>   :
>   "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:106604:32↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2710:26)↵    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35701:33)↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2709:32)↵    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2460:43)↵    at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3194:34↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31)↵    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:35692:33)↵    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36)↵    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47)"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Error

My project Structure is:
[image]

My app and environment folder consists of following files:
[image]

My app.component.ts file is

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
//import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';
import {PushService} from './push.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {


  // Declare the variables used
  messaging: any
  token: any  // Stores the current token ID instance generated
  items: AngularFireList<any[]>
  itemsDisplay: AngularFireList<any[]> // List observable for template view (Optional. items itself can be used)
  itemsArr: any[] // Stores the token IDs retrieved from the firebase database 
  hideToken: boolean = false

  // Notificayion object
  pushData: any = {
    'notification': {
      "title": "Background Message Title",
      "body": "Background Message Body"
    },
    "to": ""
  }

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, private pushService: PushService) {

    // Creates a Firebase List Observable and calls the data in it
    this.itemsDisplay = db.list('/items')

    // Declaring the property value of messaging
    this.messaging = firebase.messaging();

    // Check for token refresh
    this.messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
      this.messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(refreshedToken) {
          console.log('Token refreshed.');
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
        });
    });
    // Obtaining the firebase data and retrieving token ID values separately
    this.itemsArr = []  // Reinitialize the array to prevent data duplication
    this.items = this.db.list('/items');
    this.items.valueChanges().subscribe(snapshots => {

      console.log(snapshots);
      //snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
      //  console.log("Hey ,, snapshot......"+snapshot);
      //  this.itemsArr.push(snapshot);
      // });
    });
    // console.log(this.itemsArr)
  }

  // Check for duplicates in token subscription
  checkToken(token, arr) {
    console.log("Inside check token function")
    console.log(arr)
    console.log(token)
    let counter: number = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] === token) {
        counter++
      }
    }
    console.log("Counter value", counter)
    return counter
  }

  // Generate Push through an event
  generatePush() {
    console.log("Inside push function")
    console.log(this.pushData.to)
    if (this.pushData.to === "") {
      console.log("No token available")
      return
    }
    this.pushService.generatePush(this.pushData)
      .subscribe(data => {console.log("Succesfully Posted")}, err => console.log(err))
  }

  // Function to get the data from Firebase Database
  getDataFromFb() {
    this.hideToken = true
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Prompt user to grant permission for notifications on loading components
    const self = this
    this.items = this.db.list('/items') 
    this.messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        self.messaging.getToken()
          .then(function(currentToken) {
            if (currentToken) {
              self.token = currentToken
              self.pushData.to = self.token
              console.log(self.pushData.to)

              // Set a timeout so as to enable all the data to be loaded
              setTimeout(() => {
                if (self.checkToken(self.token, self.itemsArr) === 0) {
                  console.log("Push occurrence")
                  // self.items.push({tokenID: currentToken})
                } else {
                  console.log("User is already subscribed")
                }
              }, 6500)
              // Displays the current token data
              console.log("currentToken: ", currentToken);
              console.log("Stored token: ", self.token);
            } else {
              // Show permission request.
              console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            }
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token.', err);
          });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify. ', err);
      })

    // Handle incoming messages. Called when:
    // - a message is received while the app has focus
    // - the user clicks on an app notification created by a sevice worker `messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler` handler.
    this.messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
    });
  }

}
```

My firebase-messaging-sw.js file is:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '850143277209' // run it again show me error
});

var messaging = firebase.messaging();
currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);

// Handle Background Notifications

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should implement this optional method
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  var notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.'

  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);




});
```

My Angular.json file is:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "beautyOfSoul": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "styleext": "scss"
                }
            },
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/beautyOfSoul",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/assets/manifest.json",
                            "src/manifest.json",
                            "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": {
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "serviceWorker": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "beautyOfSoul:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "beautyOfSoul:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "beautyOfSoul:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/manifest.json",
                            "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "beautyOfSoul-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "beautyOfSoul:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "beautyOfSoul:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "beautyOfSoul"
}
```

My Network tab is:
[image]

My service worker tab is:

[image]

Comment: This might be happening because `ng-serve` does [not work with service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#serving-with-http-server), you would need to use `http-server`

Comment: I have tried it on server also. Same problem is there.

Comment: Did you try it on firefox ? I have the same error on chrome but I tested it on firefox and it works. I would like to find the answer for this cause I thaught that I receive this because my app must run in development on https and I use selfsigned certificates

Comment: @Nicu I'm getting the same error on Firefox too.

Comment: Might have something do with how firebase is trying to register the SW, try creating an empty file in root folder - `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Can you share the URL of your page by hosting in github pages may be? Its hard to debug this way. Or please share Chrome dev tools -> network tab, Application ->Service worker and Audit -> Progressive web app screenshots to know what is going wrong.

Comment: I've updated the question with screenshots of Network tab and Service worker. My Audit is not working, I don't know why. It is taking time to auditing the localhost. If you can see in the service worker tab, then you will find that the firebase services are not working fine. @Anand

Comment: so did you register the service working from app.module.ts or separately, I am facing similar issue. It would be great if you can add the exact way you able solve this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got a similar issue in React project, and for me the solution was to manually register my own js file as a serviceworker.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./your-serviceworker-file.js')
.then((registration) => {
  messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

  // Request permission and get token.....
});
```

Running that code in the firebase initialization solved the issue for me.

Comment: I have already registered my service worker file manually but I don't know why I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Where do you register it? Couldn't find the code in the code you provide in the question. This code should be run right after you create the firebase messaging object in some root level js file.

Comment: I put it inside the `app.module.ts` file : ` imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,environment.production ?ServiceWorkerModule.register('firebase-messaging-sw.js'):[],ServiceWorkerModule.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    HttpClientModule,environment.production ? ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js') : [], ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ]`

Comment: Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong in the code

Comment: I am not familiar with angular or typescript, but I guess that the service worker file should always be the same, and it seems that you have several serviceworker files (firebase-messaging-sw.js, ngsw-worker.js), if they relate to different things then it is fine. But the firebase serviceworker file should be the same throughout.

Comment: Actually it works with the answer that you provided me! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thats great! And thanks for accepting my answer aswell.

Comment: I was able to get rid of that error with the help of your answer but now I am not be able to run my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` code `return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);` as I am getting the token and when I am testing that then I am getting the information on console but Notification is not coming on the browser.

Comment: That is a different issue then and maybe a reason for another question. If I understand the question correctly, you are expecting to see notifications when you are actively on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Put your **firebase-messaging-sw.js** on the site root.

```
https://yoursite.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js
```